# Como fazer uma consulta utilizando SELECT com condições de LIKE '%%' e Igual "=" com input de textbox e dropdowlist em C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Estou fazendo uma consulta de pessoas por filtro, porém me deparei com os seguintes problemas:

1º Condição LIKE %%, (pois nem sempre o usuário irá preencher os campos "Nº do Documento" e "Nome" - retornando vazio "");

2º DropDownList quando o usuário deixa com a opção "Todos" ou "Todas", ele retorna o SelectedValue igual a zero '0'.

Gostaria que a consulta por filtro funcionasse.

**Abaixo o modelo de dados:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Abaixo a Tela Consultar Pessoas:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Abaixo parte do método ObterListaPessoasPorFiltro, junto com o SELECT que estou utilizando:**

```
command.CommandText = @"SELECT ID_PESSOA, FOTO, N_DOCUMENTO, NOME,
                                           ID_TIPO_PESSOA, DESCRICAO_TIPO, ID_STATUS, DESCRICAO_STATUS,
                                           STRING_AGG(DESCRICAO_BLOCO, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DESCRICAO_BLOCO) AS DESCRICAO_BLOCO,
                                           STRING_AGG(NOMENCLATURA, ',') AS NOMENCLATURA
                                    FROM (
                                        SELECT  PESSOAS.ID_PESSOA, PESSOAS.FOTO, PESSOAS.N_DOCUMENTO, PESSOAS.NOME, 
                                                PESSOAS.ID_TIPO_PESSOA, TIPOS_PESSOAS.DESCRICAO_TIPO, PESSOAS.ID_STATUS, STATUS.DESCRICAO_STATUS, 
                                                BLOCOS.ID_BLOCO, BLOCOS.DESCRICAO_BLOCO,            
                                                STRING_AGG(UNIDADES.NOMENCLATURA, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY UNIDADES.NOMENCLATURA) AS NOMENCLATURA            
                                            FROM ResidencialSolarDiLucca.dbo.PESSOAS
                                            INNER JOIN
                                            ResidencialSolarDiLucca.dbo.TIPOS_PESSOAS
                                            ON PESSOAS.ID_TIPO_PESSOA = TIPOS_PESSOAS.ID_TIPO_PESSOA
                                            INNER JOIN ResidencialSolarDiLucca.dbo.STATUS
                                            ON PESSOAS.ID_STATUS = STATUS.ID_STATUS
                                            LEFT JOIN PESSOAS_APARTAMENTOS
                                            ON PESSOAS.ID_PESSOA = PESSOAS_APARTAMENTOS.ID_PESSOA
                                            LEFT JOIN APARTAMENTOS
                                            ON PESSOAS_APARTAMENTOS.ID_APARTAMENTO = APARTAMENTOS.ID_APARTAMENTO
                                            LEFT JOIN ResidencialSolarDiLucca.dbo.BLOCOS
                                            ON APARTAMENTOS.ID_BLOCO = BLOCOS.ID_BLOCO
                                            LEFT JOIN ResidencialSolarDiLucca.dbo.UNIDADES
                                            ON APARTAMENTOS.ID_UNIDADE = UNIDADES.ID_UNIDADE
                                            WHERE STATUS.DESCRICAO_STATUS = 'Ativo'
                                            AND N_DOCUMENTO LIKE '%@N_DOCUMENTO%'
                                            AND NOME LIKE '%@NOME%'
                                            AND (PESSOAS.ID_TIPO_PESSOA IS NULL OR PESSOAS.ID_TIPO_PESSOA = @ID_TIPO_PESSOA)
                                            AND (PESSOAS.ID_STATUS IS NULL OR PESSOAS.ID_STATUS = @ID_STATUS)
                                            AND (APARTAMENTOS.ID_BLOCO IS NULL OR APARTAMENTOS.ID_BLOCO = @ID_BLOCO)
                                            AND (APARTAMENTOS.ID_UNIDADE IS NULL OR APARTAMENTOS.ID_UNIDADE = @ID_UNIDADE)
                                            GROUP BY PESSOAS.ID_PESSOA, PESSOAS.FOTO, PESSOAS.N_DOCUMENTO, PESSOAS.NOME,
                                                     PESSOAS.ID_TIPO_PESSOA, TIPOS_PESSOAS.DESCRICAO_TIPO, PESSOAS.ID_STATUS, STATUS.DESCRICAO_STATUS, BLOCOS.ID_BLOCO, DESCRICAO_BLOCO) AS X
                                    GROUP BY ID_PESSOA, FOTO, N_DOCUMENTO, NOME,
                                                ID_TIPO_PESSOA, DESCRICAO_TIPO, ID_STATUS, DESCRICAO_STATUS
                                    ORDER BY NOME";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_DOCUMENTO", nDocumento);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOME", nome);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_TIPO_PESSOA", idTipoPessoa);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_STATUS", idStatus);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_BLOCO", idBloco);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_UNIDADE", idUnidade);
```

Comment: Eu removi a primeira condição "STATUS.DESCRICAO_STATUS = 'Ativo'", pois estava repetida logo a baixo.

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta para fazer correções e incluir mais informações sobre o problema, caso necessário.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a melhor resposta até o momento, mas o que mais chegou próximo.
Ao invés de trabalhar com os ID troquei pelas DESCRICÕES.

**Obtive a entrada dos dados da seguinte maneira:**

```
string nDocumento = Regex.Replace(txtNDocumento.Text.ToUpper().Trim(), "[^xX0-9,]", "");
string nome = txtNome.Text.ToUpper().Trim();            
string descricaoTipo = DdlTipoPessoa.SelectedItem.Text;                        
            if (descricaoTipo == "Todos")
            {
                descricaoTipo = "";
            }
        string descricaoStatus = DdlStatus.SelectedItem.Text;
            if (descricaoStatus == "Todos")
            {
                descricaoStatus = "";
            }
        string descricaoBloco = ddlBlocos.SelectedItem.Text;
            if (descricaoBloco == "Todos")
            {
                descricaoBloco = "";
            }
        string descricaoUnidade = ddlUnidades.SelectedItem.Text;
            if (descricaoUnidade == "Todas")
            {
                descricaoUnidade = "";
            }
```

**Alterei as condições WHERE do SQL para:**

```
WHERE N_DOCUMENTO LIKE '%' + @N_DOCUMENTO + '%'
AND NOME LIKE '%' + @NOME + '%'       
AND (PESSOAS.ID_TIPO_PESSOA IS NULL OR TIPOS_PESSOAS.DESCRICAO_TIPO LIKE '%' + @DESCRICAO_TIPO + '%')
AND (PESSOAS.ID_STATUS IS NULL OR STATUS.DESCRICAO_STATUS LIKE '%' + @DESCRICAO_STATUS + '%')
AND (APARTAMENTOS.ID_BLOCO IS NULL OR BLOCOS.DESCRICAO_BLOCO LIKE '%' + @DESCRICAO_BLOCO + '%')
AND (APARTAMENTOS.ID_UNIDADE IS NULL OR UNIDADES.NOMENCLATURA LIKE '%' + @NOMENCLATURA + '%')
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça detalhes adicionais em sua resposta. Como está escrita atualmente, é difícil entender sua solução.